# Huawei doesnt update location using Google maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, huawei-mobile-services

I have a location tracking feature in my app, it works just fine in Samsung devices, but when I run it in Huawei it crashes says mLastLocation is null.

I'm using Google maps API V2 location callbacks in onCreate method:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            if (locationResult == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (mLastLocation == null)
                return;

        }
    };
mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
```

It always return because mLastLocation is always null in Huawei! 
Is there something to do for devices other than Samsung?

Comment: `locationResult` is from the callback method, but where did the `mLastLocation` appear from ?

Comment: Im not showing the entire codes, it appears above

Comment: As i said it works just fine in Samsung devices

Comment: So then we are trying to fix something that we don't know ? You are saying it's null and the app is getting crashed. But you didn't provide more information about your question.

Comment: I've edited my question